# Cant install Steam on my ubuntu 17.04 64 bit

Tags: dpkg, steam

When I run `sudo apt-get install steam` in the terminal, I get these errors:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libudev1:i386:
 libudev1:i386 depends on libgcc1 (>= 1:4.2); however:
  Package libgcc1:i386 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libudev1:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgl1-mesa-dri:i386:
 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 depends on libgcc1 (>= 1:3.4); however:
  Package libgcc1:i386 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libc6:i386:
 libc6:i386 depends on libgcc1; however:
  Package libgcc1:i386 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libc6:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libtxc-dxtn-s2tc:i386:
 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.4); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libtxc-dxtn-s2tc:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpcre3:i386:
 libpcre3:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.4); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libpcre3:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libglapi-mesa:i386:
 libglapi-mesa:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.4); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglapi-mesa:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libblkid1:i386:
 libblkid1:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.17); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libblkid1:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libdrm2:i386:
 libdrm2:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.17); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libdrm2:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libxcb-sync1:i386:
 libxcb-sync1:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.4); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libxcb-sync1:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgpg-error0:i386:
 libgpg-error0:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.15); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgpg-error0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libdrm-intel1:i386:
 libdrm-intel1:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.17); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.
 libdrm-intel1:i386 depends on libdrm2 (>= 2.4.38); however:
  Package libdrm2:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libdrm-intel1:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libx11-xcb1:i386:
 libx11-xcb1:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.1.3); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libx11-xcb1:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libllvm4.0:i386:
 libllvm4.0:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.15); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.
 libllvm4.0:i386 depends on libgcc1 (>= 1:4.2); however:
  Package libgcc1:i386 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libllvm4.0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgl1-mesa-glx:i386:
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.8); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 depends on libdrm2 (>= 2.4.66); however:
  Package libdrm2:i386 is not configured yet.
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 depends on libglapi-mesa (= 17.0.3-1ubuntu1); however:
  Package libglapi-mesa:i386 is not configured yet.
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 depends on libx11-xcb1; however:
  Package libx11-xcb1:i386 is not configured yet.
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 depends on libxcb-sync1; however:
  Package libxcb-sync1:i386 is not configured yet.
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 depends on libgl1-mesa-dri; however:
  Package libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libselinux1:i386:
 libselinux1:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.8); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.
 libselinux1:i386 depends on libpcre3; however:
  Package libpcre3:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libselinux1:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpciaccess0:i386:
 libpciaccess0:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.7); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libpciaccess0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libsensors4:i386:
 libsensors4:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.4); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libsensors4:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libstdc++6:i386:
 libstdc++6:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.18); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.
 libstdc++6:i386 depends on libgcc1 (>= 1:4.2); however:
  Package libgcc1:i386 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libstdc++6:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libffi6:i386:
 libffi6:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.7); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libffi6:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libdrm-radeon1:i386:
 libdrm-radeon1:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.4); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.
 libdrm-radeon1:i386 depends on libdrm2 (>= 2.4.38); however:
  Package libdrm2:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libdrm-radeon1:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcomerr2:i386:
 libcomerr2:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.17); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libcomerr2:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libxdmcp6:i386:
 libxdmcp6:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.4); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libxdmcp6:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libmount1:i386:
 libmount1:i386 depends on libblkid1 (>= 2.17.2); however:
  Package libblkid1:i386 is not configured yet.
 libmount1:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.17); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.
 libmount1:i386 depends on libselinux1 (>= 2.6-3~); however:
  Package libselinux1:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libmount1:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libxxf86vm1:i386:
 libxxf86vm1:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.4); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libxxf86vm1:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libdrm-nouveau2:i386:
 libdrm-nouveau2:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.4); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.
 libdrm-nouveau2:i386 depends on libdrm2 (>= 2.4.38); however:
  Package libdrm2:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libdrm-nouveau2:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libxcb1:i386:
 libxcb1:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.4); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.
 libxcb1:i386 depends on libxdmcp6; however:
  Package libxdmcp6:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libxcb1:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libxau6:i386:
 libxau6:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.4); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libxau6:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libedit2:i386:
 libedit2:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.17); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libedit2:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libncurses5:i386:
 libncurses5:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.4); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libncurses5:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libxcb-present0:i386:
 libxcb-present0:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.4); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.
 libxcb-present0:i386 depends on libxcb1; however:
  Package libxcb1:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libxcb-present0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libtinfo5:i386:
 libtinfo5:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.16); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libtinfo5:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libxinerama1:i386:
 libxinerama1:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.1.3); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libxinerama1:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libxcb-dri2-0:i386:
 libxcb-dri2-0:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.4); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.
 libxcb-dri2-0:i386 depends on libxcb1; however:
  Package libxcb1:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libxcb-dri2-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libxcb-dri3-0:i386:
 libxcb-dri3-0:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.4); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.
 libxcb-dri3-0:i386 depends on libxcb1 (>= 1.9.2); however:
  Package libxcb1:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libxcb-dri3-0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libxcb-glx0:i386:
 libxcb-glx0:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.4); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.
 libxcb-glx0:i386 depends on libxcb1; however:
  Package libxcb1:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libxcb-glx0:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libexpat1:i386:
 libexpat1:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.4); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libexpat1:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of liblzma5:i386:
 liblzma5:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.17); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package liblzma5:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libxdamage1:i386:
 libxdamage1:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.1.3); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libxdamage1:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of liblz4-1:i386:
 liblz4-1:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.4); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package liblz4-1:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libxext6:i386:
 libxext6:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.4); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libxext6:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libxfixes3:i386:
 libxfixes3:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.4); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libxfixes3:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libdrm-amdgpu1:i386:
 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.17); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.
 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 depends on libdrm2 (>= 2.4.60); however:
  Package libdrm2:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgcrypt20:i386:
 libgcrypt20:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.15); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.
 libgcrypt20:i386 depends on libgpg-error0 (>= 1.14); however:
  Package libgpg-error0:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgcrypt20:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libuuid1:i386:
 libuuid1:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.4); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libuuid1:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgpm2:i386:
 libgpm2:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.15); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgpm2:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of zlib1g:i386:
 zlib1g:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.4); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package zlib1g:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libelf1:i386:
 libelf1:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.4); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.
 libelf1:i386 depends on zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4); however:
  Package zlib1g:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libelf1:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libxss1:i386:
 libxss1:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.1.3); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.
 libxss1:i386 depends on libxext6; however:
  Package libxext6:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libxss1:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libxshmfence1:i386:
 libxshmfence1:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.4); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libxshmfence1:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libx11-6:i386:
 libx11-6:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.15); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.
 libx11-6:i386 depends on libxcb1 (>= 1.11.1); however:
  Package libxcb1:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libx11-6:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 libudev1:i386
 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
 libc6:i386
 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc:i386
 libpcre3:i386
 libglapi-mesa:i386
 libblkid1:i386
 libdrm2:i386
 libxcb-sync1:i386
 libgpg-error0:i386
 libdrm-intel1:i386
 libx11-xcb1:i386
 libllvm4.0:i386
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
 libselinux1:i386
 libpciaccess0:i386
 libsensors4:i386
 libstdc++6:i386
 libffi6:i386
 libdrm-radeon1:i386
 libcomerr2:i386
 libxdmcp6:i386
 libmount1:i386
 libxxf86vm1:i386
 libdrm-nouveau2:i386
 libxcb1:i386
 libxau6:i386
 libedit2:i386
 libncurses5:i386
 libxcb-present0:i386
 libtinfo5:i386
 libxinerama1:i386
 libxcb-dri2-0:i386
 libxcb-dri3-0:i386
 libxcb-glx0:i386
 libexpat1:i386
 liblzma5:i386
 libxdamage1:i386
 liblz4-1:i386
 libxext6:i386
 libxfixes3:i386
 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386
 libgcrypt20:i386
 libuuid1:i386
 libgpm2:i386
 zlib1g:i386
 libelf1:i386
 libxss1:i386
 libxshmfence1:i386
 libx11-6:i386
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Although is there a reason that some parts are all the way to the right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step to fixing this is to enable support for 32 bit binaries. You can do this by running

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 && sudo apt update
```

Now try installing steam again either from the official site using `dpkg` or using `sudo apt install steam`

If this still doesn't work, try installing the packages manually.

1. Open up https://packages.ubuntu.com/ in your web browser.
2. Scroll down to the `Search package directories` area.
3. Select your version of ubuntu from the `Distribution` drop down (In this case it's `Zesty`).
4. Type in the package name and click search (In this case it's `libgcc1`)
5. Click on the `Exact Hit` (In this case it's `Package libgcc1`)
6. Select i386 in the table at the bottom
7. Select one of the links on the page. It's probably a good idea to select the one for your country but it doesn't matter.
8. Open up a terminal and navigate to the directory that you downloaded the package to.
9. Run `sudo dpkg -i file.deb`, where `file.deb` is the file that you just downloaded.

Once this is done, try to install steam again.

If it gives you the `depends on` error for a different package, just follow steps 1-9 for that package and try to install steam. You may have to do this multiple times.

Comment: Tried it but resulting the same error.   Ihave also tried from store it  struck at 50%.

Comment: What type of computer are you using? I've just had a proper look at it, it is trying to install 32 bit packages. Your computer might be 64 bit, or maybe it's an ARM computer (e.g. Raspberry Pi).

Comment: Dell inspiron 3542 i5 64bit

Comment: The problem here is that you are trying to install 32 bit software on a 64 bit computer. According to [this](https://akrabat.com/installing-32-bit-packages-on-ubuntu-14-04/) website, you need to add a 32 bit architecture to apt by running `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`. Then run `sudo apt update` to add all of the 32 bit packages to the database and try to reinstall

Comment: If this works, I will delete my original answer and add this as an answer

Comment: nope, that didn't.

Comment: Try downloading `libgcc1` from here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/i386/libgcc1/download. Does it install properly. If not, could you post the errors

Comment: I've completely changed the instructions to what you did in these comments. @muppanenibharath

Comment: Could you mention that your computer is 64 bit in the question? @muppanenibharath

Comment: The solution from this answer did not help me in my situation. For me, the problematic package was `libmount1:i386`. Removing it with `sudo apt remove libmount1:i386` cleared the problem and let Apt reinstall what it needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get -f install`.

That should download your dependencies, then continue with the Steam installation.

Comment: Sudo apt-get -f install  resulting same error ending with                                  
           E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)